# I've committed zina and feel guilty. How do I tell my wife for forgiveness and then do tauba?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sharia, zina

What to for tauba? I fear if I tell my wife she will never trust me again. Can i do one sunna my entire life for Allah to exept my tauba

Answer (score 3):

و عليكم السلام والرحمة الله وبركاته

Firstly, do not disclose this to your wife. Keep this between you and Allah so that the sin is shielded by As-Sitteer in this world and on the day of judgement.

Secondly, Follow the link provided by @UmH to perform sincere Tawba.